# Remove None from the output of a function call

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def digits_plus(num):
    for i in range (num+1):
        print (str(i)+"+",end="")

print (digits_plus(3))
```

Here's what I got returned:

```
0+1+2+3+None
```

"None" always exists at the last of the line returned.

I want this returned:

```
0+1+2+3+
```

BTW. I'm totally new to programming.I did some research myself, but the answers weren't helpful. They all tell me to remove `print` but I want the string in the same line so I must also include `end=""`. Help please.

Comment: Your code as written gives an IndentationError.

Comment: I'll just leave this here... as an alternative solution `"+".join(map(str, range(num + 1)))`

Comment: There needs to be something else which causes the issue. At the moment your code doesn't run at all because it is not indented properly (maybe because you didn't copy and paste it exactly). And if it is indented properly (like in [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40312716/473890)) it doesn't cause your problem.

Comment: Sorry, i made some mistake. I posted wrong function. Here's the function I meant to post.

Comment: You're printing the result of `digits_plus` (which doesn't return anything). Try just calling it.

Answer (score 9):

The reason this is happening to you is that you are *printing* the result of your function call, in this line here:

```
print(digits_plus(3))
```

But your function does not return any value, so it returns `None`. And `None` is being printed because you are telling Python to print it. (And it's on the same line as the rest because none of your other `print`s print a newline.) To solve this, change that line to just:

```
digits_plus(3)
```

Your function is doing the printing, so there is no need to also print the function's return value.

(You could also revise your function to *return* the desired value instead of printing it, which would make it more generally useful.)

Comment: Might want to add a not about printing a final newline. That's the reason that None ends up on the same line as the rest, to OP's confusion.

Answer (score 0):

A more “Pythonic” solution, using `str.join`:

```
def digits_plus(num):
    return '+'.join(str(i) for i in range(num + 1))

>>> print(digits_plus(3))
0+1+2+3
```

While Python doesn't *enforce* [command-query separation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command%E2%80%93query_separation), it's generally considered best for a function to `return` a value *xor* perform a side effect (like printing), but not both.  (Though, the standard library has exceptions to this rule, like `list.pop`.)

Also note the `+ 1` in the `range` call, since `range` does not include its upper bound.

Comment: Would more pythonic be `digits_plus = lambda num: "+".join(map(str, range(num + 1)))`?

Comment: @cricket_007 The [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations) recommends to not assign lambda statements to variables but to use `def`.

Answer (score -1):

Your issue that `digit_plus` returns `None` by default. Using no `return` statement at all or just `return` will implicitly return `None`. So the easiest fix would be to just not print the result of `digit_plus`, and only calling it.

But this will still print a “+” at the end. To solve that use `"+".join()` like others suggested or add some logic to only add “+” if there are still items left. One way to do it is this way:

```
for i in range(num + 1):
    if i > 0:  # not the first time
        print("+", end="")
    print(i, end="")
```

In that case `str(i)` can be replaced by `i` as `print()` does it implicitly anyway.